# Selecting codeship steps based in a single repo based on files changed

Tags: codeship

I have a repository that build and deploys two different components - a frontend and a backend. Each of these have a specific set of steps that need to be executed for the CICD. Is there a way to run a selective set of steps based on which component has actually changed. For e.g. let us say all my frontend is under frontend/ and all my backend is under backend/. Is there a way to run a selective set of steps when there are changes only in the frontend ?

Answer (score 0):

The closest approach would be to adopt branch naming conventions that separate frontend and backend test builds.

For example, you could manage all frontend work with a `frontend-` prefix and all backend work with a `backend-` prefix. The `codeship-steps.yml` would then be implemented as:

```
- name: Frontend tests
  service: your-app
  type: serial
  tag: ^frontend-
  steps:
    - service: your-app
      command: ./run-frontend-test.sh
    - [other step commands...]
- name: Backend tests
  service: your-app
  type: serial
  tag: ^backend-
  steps:
    - service: your-app
      command: ./run-backend-test.sh
    - [other step commands...]
```

See [here](https://documentation.codeship.com/pro/builds-and-configuration/steps/#limiting-steps-to-specific-branches-or-tags) for more.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, branch naming convention is something that I had thought of as well; I was however trying to avoid that since that is an additional step that developers have to remember to name the branch correctly. I was wondering if there are other ways to achieve the same in codeship.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I created a bash script that performs a `git diff` on the selected folder, but I'm getting a "not a git repository" error so I guess that codeship doesn't reveal git files during the test execution?